KQL Query to filter duplicate entries and select top 1 from the log data
I am using below query to get the container error log and filtering to remove duplicates.
    let ContainerIdList = KubePodInventory
    | where ContainerName contains "acc-c1-logger"
    | where Namespace has "prd" | where ClusterId =~ '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/aksprd'
   | distinct ContainerID;
   ContainerLog 
   | where ContainerID in (ContainerIdList)
   | where LogEntry !has "SRV1174"
   | where LogEntry has "| E |" or LogEntry has "| F |"
   | where LogEntry !contains "the I/O interface definition of project" 
   | where LogEntry !contains "the I/O interface definition of cuc" 
   | where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)
   | project LogEntrySource, LogEntry, TimeGenerated 
   | order by TimeGenerated desc
   | top 1000 by LogEntry
   | render table
   | extend SplitLog = split(LogEntry, "|")
   | project C1 = SplitLog[0], cc=SplitLog[1],C2 = todatetime(SplitLog[1]), C3 = 
     SplitLog[2], C4 = SplitLog[3], C5=SplitLog[4], logerror=SplitLog[5]
   | summarize arg_max(C2,*) by tostring(logerror)
   | project-away logerror
   | project ERROR = strcat( cc, "|", C3, "|", C4, "|", C5, "|", logerror1)

i get following output in the error table
  2024-06-27 20:43:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2006 | E | [DB_AdviceSimulationAlerted] on project 
  'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement 
   with handle 7."
   2024-06-27 20:44:00 | con-prc-sc | SRV2001 | E | Unable to connect DB

   2024-06-27 20:44:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2006 | E | [DB_AdviceSimulationAlerted] on project 
  'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement 
   with handle 9."
   2024-06-27 20:45:00 | con-prc-sc | SRV2001 | E | file is missing on relative path

   2024-06-27 20:45:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2006 | E | [DB_Advice] on project 
  'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement 
   with handle 11."

the requirement is here , i need to get only top 1 from the could not fine prepared statement error along with other errors.
 The Expected outcome should be 
 Error:
 2024-06-27 20:43:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2006 | E | 
 [DB_AdviceSimulationAlerted] on project 
 'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find 
 prepared statement with handle 7."
 2024-06-27 20:44:00 | con-prc-sc | SRV2001 | E | Unable to connect DB
 2024-06-27 20:45:00 | con-prc-sc | SRV2001 | E | file is missing on 
 relative path

thanks in advance

You could do the following directly below your last line of your Query:
Data is only for reproducing your data.
let Data = datatable(ERROR: string)
[
   "2024-06-27 20:43:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2005 | E | [DB_AdviceSimulationAlerted] on project 'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement with handle 11.",
   "2024-06-27 20:43:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2005 | E | [DB_AdviceSimulationAlerted] on project 'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement with handle 9.",
   "2024-06-27 20:43:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2006 | E | [DB_AdviceSimulationAlerted] on project 'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement with handle 7.",
   "2024-06-27 20:44:00 | con-prc-sc | SRV2001 | E | Unable to connect DB",
   "2024-06-27 20:44:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2006 | E | [DB_AdviceSimulationAlerted] on project 'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement with handle 9.",
   "2024-06-27 20:45:00 | con-prc-sc | SRV2001 | E | file is missing on relative path",
   "2024-06-27 20:45:47 | con-prc-sc | SRV2006 | E | [DB_Advice] on project 'Advice': error while storing: During executeUpdate: Could not find prepared statement with handle 11."
];
Data
| extend type = tostring(split(ERROR, "|")[2])
| extend ts = tostring(split(ERROR, "|")[0])
| extend message = tostring(split(ERROR, "|")[4])
| extend type = iff(message contains "Could not find prepared statement with handle", "A", strcat(type, message))
| order by type desc, ts desc
| extend HasPrev = prev(type) == type
| where HasPrev == false
| project ERROR

Demo here
Result:


Does it ignore other errors ?if so that should not be the case

No its not ignoring other errors. But you have to test it of course. If something is still wrong we can fix it!

i have tested this, i can see it is ignoring other errors, even we can see it in your result output, it is not listing error Unable to connect DB

I thought, that was your requirement. Then delete the line | where ERROR has "Could not find prepared statement" Then you have every error.

The important part is the line with HasPrev. All other lines are only to showcase the result.

I tried removing the line, its listing only first error and ignoring all others

When you click at the demo link in my answer it is working. But I only used test data. The HasPrev by Type looks at the "SRV2005" strings. If there are more of the same strings, only the first will be added to the result. Maybe you have to change this criteria. But now my query is summarizing every different Type and gives only one per type. Thats the part of: "top 1 from the could not fine prepared statement error"

Maybe you have no other errors because of your timeframe of 5 minutes.

you are correct, SRV2005 has different errors along with prepared statement.  this query is picking only top1 from the list,  any other solution that will pick top1 from prepared statement error and list it along with the rest of the errors ?

What is the expected outcome out of your sample data in your question?

i updated the question with expected outcome, it is like 1 out 3 prepared statement errors with other two unique errors. thanks for your help

in demo results, first two are same type error(prepared) listed, need to list only one. but i think we cannot go beyond this. thanks for your help. really amazing skills. thank you very much

You´re welcome. But why are the first two the same in the my demo results?

we need only one entry for all errors that contains string could not find prepared statement errors, if you  see in demo results first and second entries are same as they contain could not find  prepared statement error. is it possible to make it one irrespective of error type and other strings in log.

Now my Query is fixed in my answer.  Please have a look.
